# Drupal moving installation from subfolder to root

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-7, installation

I installed my Drupal website in `www.example.com/drupal`,and now I just want to move it to the root(www.example.com).
I have tried to copy all folders inside /drupal folder to the root and then change the line

```
$base_url = 'http://www.example.com/drupal';
```

into

```
$base_url = 'http://www.example.com';
```

in my setting.php located in `/drupal/sites/default/`

When I proceed like that I 'm getting all links remaining with the old format(`http://www.example.com/drupal/.....`) and a warning of Path permissions(`pathFinder Redirect: not done due to bypass pathfinder redirect permission`),apart the frontpage.

I didn't touch to the `.htaccess`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Are you using 'URL aliases' in your drupal site?

Comment: yes automatic aliases

Comment: Can you see that are you setting path alias for all website links in URL Aliases configuration ?

Comment: Yes I can access manually to the URL aliases configuration.But everytime I access to the link(Drupal management),I have the old URLversion(example.com/drupal/admin/structure for example)and I have to change it manually everytime

Comment: If possible restart server and clear drupal cache and see

Comment: Yeah I already tried but withouth results

Comment: your root folder is your site name right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78859/discussion-between-alex-and-sagar).

Comment: and while copying all folders inside /drupal folder to the root, please make sure that you should copy /drupal folder itself not by individual sub folders of /drupal., because /drupal migh have hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of server's Rewrite Rule feature for this.